# Cant open connection

Tags: node.js, database, connection, informix

Im having a problem when i open connection in onedb informixdb. I try everything like manual install, searching for similar errors, but nothing works, somebody has any idea?

[image: ERROR IMAGE]

**Context**: NodeJS 14, Informixdb node module.

**OS**: Ubuntu 20.04 x86_64

**Library**: https://github.com/OpenInformix/node-informixdb

**PS**: I tried with and without driver. The connection works only in windows OS locally, in linux azure not works.

code:

```
const dbConfig = `
  DRIVER={HCL INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)};
  SERVER=server;
  DATABASE=db;
  HOST=127.0.0.1;
  SERVICE=9001;
  UID=user;
  PWD=p@sSword;`

const test = informix.open(dbConfig, (err, conn) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Erro ao abrir a conexão:', err)
    // reject(err) // Reject the promise if there's an error
    console.log("Conection error", err)
    console.log("Conection open", conn)
    return
  }
})
console.log("---->", test)
```

Im trying to open connection in onedb informixdb.

Comment: Hey! I suggest providing an error output so it can be copied erc. Also, please provide more information about the steps you've taken to reproduce this error.

Comment: @Saraf oks, i add some info about code and a image about error